# Unique constraint violation in PostgreSQL Trigger

Tags: postgresql-9.1, database-trigger, unique-constraint

I have below two tables. I wrote after insert trigger on employees table. If i insert the record in employees table it will insert the record in employee_audits table.

Both table have primary key column (id). suppose if you try to insert record ID value which does not exists in employees table and exists in employee_audits table, it shows the
error duplicate key value violates unique constraint "employee_audits_pkey" and also it is not inserting record in  employees table. Both transaction failed. 
But i want to insert the record  in employees table.

```
CREATE TABLE employees(
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   first_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE employee_audits (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   changed_on TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL
)
```

The trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_last_name_changes()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO employee_audits(last_name,changed_on)
   VALUES(NEW.last_name,now());
   RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

The trigger definition:

```
CREATE TRIGGER last_name_changes
  AFTER INSERT
  ON employees
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_last_name_changes();
```

```
INSERT INTO employees (first_name, last_name)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe');

SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES
```

```
id first_name   last_name
1  "John"        "Doe"
```

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_AUDITS
```

```
ID   last_name  CHANGED_ON
1      "Doe"    "2019-12-27 17:21:13.934"
```

Manual insert on second table

```
insert into employee_audits values(2,'banu','2019-12-27 17:21:13.934')
```

Manual insert on first table

```
INSERT INTO employees (first_name, last_name)
VALUES ('David', 'Raj');
```

> Error duplicate key value violates unique constraint "employee_audits_pkey"

is it possible to insert record in employees table?

Comment: If the "ID" in your audit table is the customer's ID, you can't really have unique index on it, because that doesn't really work if the name is changed more than once...

Comment: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: @JamesZ: `employee_audits.id` is not the customer's ID - it's an auto-generated value. But the manual insert with a value bypassing the sequence breaks the generation.

Comment: I thought it's supposed to be a generated key, but if there's no link to customer id, there's no way of telling which customer name was changed -- so the table definitely needs to have that id too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `serial` column you should never provide the value for it manually. Manually providing a value for a `serial` will **not** advance the sequence behind that column, so the next time you insert without specifying the `id` column, the next sequence value will be taken which is `2` as the sequence was only advanced once.

So instead of:

```
insert into employee_audits values(2,'banu','2019-12-27 17:21:13.934')
```

Just use:

```
insert into employee_audits (last_name, changed_at)
values ('banu','2019-12-27 17:21:13.934');
```

This behaviour of the `serial` columns is one of the reasons why it's [highly recommended](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) to use `identity` columns with modern Postgres versions.

Comment: ok thanks.is it possible to insert record in employees table if i remove serial in both tables and try to insert record in employees table even it is in employee_audits table.i want to insert record in employees table even it failed to insert record in employee_audits table.

Comment: You can insert as many rows manually in the `employees` or `employee_audit` table as you want. Just make sure you never bypass the sequence.

Comment: i will start new thread to clarify my doubts without serial or sequence column

Comment: suppose if want to insert record in employees table only and avoiding the unique constraint in employee_audits table by using any exception handling in above trigger.